# Build Qt project with MinGW to use WinRT APIs

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, c++-winrt

I would like to use libraries available via WinRT API (like [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/)) from my application created using Qt 5.9.2 MinGW 32bit. I got Windows 10 OS.

Now, I have set up a kit as presented below.

[image: MinGW Kit Setup]

Then, in `.pro` file, I have added:

```
CONFIG += c++1z

SOURCES += main.cpp

 ### Windows 10 SDK

 win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.16299.0/um/x86/' -lWindowsApp
 else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.16299.0/um/x86/' -lWindowsApp

 INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/shared'
 DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/shared'
 INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/um'
 DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/um'
 INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/ucrt'
 DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/ucrt'
 INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/include'
 DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/include'
 INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../ne-patient-app-libraries/cppwinrt/10.0.16299.0/
 DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../ne-patient-app-libraries/cppwinrt/10.0.16299.0/
```

I got `cppwinrt` from [GitHub rep](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt) and Windows 10 SDK from [Windows Dev Center](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

I just added some lines in `main.cpp` to test proper compilation:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.WiFi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    WiFiAdapter wiFiAdapter;

    return a.exec();
}
```

After running `qmake` and `build`, I am getting these errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h:31: error: #error Unsupported architecture
>            #error Unsupported architecture
>             ^
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\new:23: error: #error Unsupported architecture
>      #error Unsupported architecture
>       ^
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\winnt.h:1008: error: #error Must define a target architecture.
>    #error Must define a target architecture.
>     ^

... and others from files: `corecrt_stdio_config.h`, `winnt.h`, `oaidl.h`, `DirectXMath.h`, `vcruntime.h` and `yvals.h`.

This is the detailed build command run by the compiler:

```
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=gnu++1z -Wextra -Wall -W -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../uwp-test -I. -I"../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/shared" -I"../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/um" -I"../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/ucrt" -I"../../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/include" -I../ne-patient-app-libraries/cppwinrt/10.0.16299.0 -I../../../../Qt/5.9.2/mingw53_32/include -I../../../../Qt/5.9.2/mingw53_32/include/QtCore -Idebug -I../../../../Qt/5.9.2/mingw53_32/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o debug/main.o ../uwp-test/main.cpp
```

What am I missing? What could solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure this is even possible. You will probably have to use msvc.

Comment: As far as I understand, only MSVC is officially supported, with Clang serving as a secondary compiler to ensure standard conformance. If you cannot use MSVC your best option would be to switch to Clang.

Comment: You may need to use `-std=c++17` or `-std=gnu++17` if you need GNU features. The C++/WinRT requires C++17. The Visual Studio also uses the `/await` option that enables some experimental and Technical Specification compiler functionality for coroutines and I am not sure if that is needed as well.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue using MSVC, the solution would be to `#include <windows.h>`. This should work as well with `mingw-64`, although their support might not be complete.